# How to compose request for REST web method in fiddler

Tags: web-services, rest, servicestack, fiddler

I am able to call web serivce but name property is not binding.

Fiddler request

```
POST http://localhost:50399/api/custservice/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost: 50399
Content-Length: 28
{ "request": { "name":"test"}}
```

POST Webmethod

```
public string Any(CustomerRequest request)
{
  //return details
}
```

CustomerRequest.cs

```
public class CustomerRequest 
{
  public string name {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

First of all you need to add Content-Type 'application/json' to the request:

```
POST http://localhost:50399/api/custservice/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost: 50399
Content-Type: application/json
```

Then change your POST data to:

```
{"name":"test"}
```

You will be able to access the data using:

```
public string Any(CustomerRequest request)
{
  return request.name
}
```

Alternatively using your existing POST data structure create a new class:

```
public class RequestWrapper
{
  public CustomerRequest request { get; set; }
}
```

and change your Action method to:

```
public string Any(RequestWrapper wrapper)
{
  return wrapper.request.name;
}
```

Comment: May I know use of RequestWrapper, if I am able to bind by just passing parameters normally.

Comment: If you are just sending {"name":"test"} then there is no need for the RequestWrapper.

Comment: I missed Content-Type:application/json so I wasn't getting response.Thanks for the answer.