# WCF RESTful Service - HTTP POST Request

Tags: wcf, http-post, httprequest, fiddler

I developed a WCF Service with the following post method:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    UriTemplate = "/InsertBearingData")]
bool InsertBearingData(String JSONString);
```

I am using Fiddler to formulate an HTTP POST Request for this method but, it is returning `Status Code - 400 Bad Request`. This is the request formulated:

**Request Header:**

```
Host: localhost:21468
Content-Length: 96
Content-Type: application/json
```

**Request Body:**

```
[{"start time":"29-03-2013 11:20:11.340","direction":"SW","end time":"29-03-2013 11:20:14.770"}]
```

Can you please tell me how to formulate a good request in order to get a succesful response?

Comment: How are you hosting the service? What is the URI of the request?

Comment: I just hit run in Visual Studio. The URI is: http://localhost:21468/DBService.svc/InsertBearingData

Comment: You said `I'm using Fiddler to formulate an HTTP POST` - which URL did you use on Fiddler? And what's the project type in Visual Studio (i.e., what are you running)?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413101/how-to-compose-request-for-rest-web-method-in-fiddler ?

Comment: It is a WCF Service Application. The URI used in Fiddler is: localhost:21468/DBService.svc/InsertBearingData

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code:

- The data type of the parameter is string, but you're passing a JSON array to it; a string parameter requires a JSON string to be passed.
- The body style of the operation is set to `Wrapped`, which means that the parameter should be *wrapped* in an object whose key is the parameter name, something like `{"JSONString":<the actual parameter value>}`

To receive a request like the one you're sending, you need to have an operation like the following:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITest
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "/InsertBearingData")]
    bool InsertBearingData(MyType[] param);
}

[DataContract]
public class MyType
{
    [DataMember(Name = "start time")]
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "end time")]
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "direction")]
    public string Direction { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. One last question: if I send an array with more than one record, how will I iterate through it in the method InsertBearingData

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake in my code - the operation parameter type should be an *array* of `MyType`, since the input is a JSON array. I edited the post to correct it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had already figured it out. Instead of an array I did a `List<MyType>` and it worked too